# Make jQuery dynamic fields unique

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, dynamic

I have fields in form which I add dynamically. How can I check if values of these fields unique?

HTML:

```
<div class="inputs">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="regSection" name="regSection[]" required="required">
</div>
<a href="#" id="#add">ADD</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#add').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('<input type="text" class="form-control" id="regSection" name="regSection[]">').fadeIn('slow').appendTo('.inputs');
});
```

Comment: firstly, there no need to add `#` in the id. `#` is just a selector for ids

Comment: second, ID's must be unique. All you input fields will get the same ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've removed the id from the input as ID's must be unique.

This code will return `found` id the values in textbox repeat. Otherwise, it will return `not found`.

```js
$('#add').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('<input type="text" class="form-control" n ame="regSection[]">').appendTo('.inputs');
});

$('#check').click(function(e){
    var arr = [];
    var found = 0;
    $('.inputs input').each(function(){
        var myVal = $(this).val();
        if(arr.includes(myVal))
            found++;
        else
            arr.push(myVal);
    });
    
    if(found) 
        console.log('found');
    else 
        console.log('unique');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inputs">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="regSection[]" required="required">
</div>
<a href="#" id="add">ADD</a>

<button id="check">Check</button>
```

Comment: thanks a lot! About ID - it's just an example code, my code is too long. I didn't notice this id. And this solution is what I need!

Comment: glad it helped :) you can mark this as the answer if it solved your problem :)